# .NET MAUI - CollectionView Lagging

Tags: c#, maui, maui-android

i am currently trying to migrate my Xamarin.Forms App to .NET MAUI. I am focusing on getting it to work on Android right now and I am now stuck on a pretty weird problem. I have a TileView that basically just displays blocks of Image+Text, all inside a Border. When I made the jump to MAUI, I noticed the entire View being incredibly laggy. That was when I used a ScrollView containing a Grid.

I asked around and I was told to use CollectionView for when I want to display multiple Images, etc.

So I started recreating the whole thing with CollectionView and its own ViewModel:

```cs
collectionView = new CollectionView();

collectionView.BindingContext = tileViewModel;
BindingContext = tileViewModel;
collectionView.SetBinding(ItemsView.ItemsSourceProperty, "Tiles");
collectionView.SetAppThemeColor(BackgroundColorProperty, Colors.White, (Color)App.Current.Resources["GBDarkGrey"]);
ContentView cw = new ContentView();
cw.Padding = new Thickness(10, 10, 10, 10);
var layout = new GridItemsLayout(2, ItemsLayoutOrientation.Vertical) { HorizontalItemSpacing = 5, VerticalItemSpacing = 5};
collectionView.ItemsLayout = layout;
collectionView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() => {
 
    Grid grid = new Grid();
    grid.RowSpacing = 5;
    grid.AddRowDefinition(new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto});
    grid.AddRowDefinition(new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto});
               
    Image image = new Image();
    var width = DeviceDisplay.Current.MainDisplayInfo.Width / DeviceDisplay.Current.MainDisplayInfo.Density;
 
    image.WidthRequest = width * 0.25;
 
 
    // image.WidthRequest = width * 0.25;
    image.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, "ImageSource", BindingMode.OneTime);
 
    Label text = new Label
    {
        FontSize = 20,
        LineBreakMode = LineBreakMode.WordWrap,
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
        HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center
    };
 
    text.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Text", BindingMode.OneTime);
               
 
    Border border = new Border();
    CompressedLayout.SetIsHeadless(image, true);
    CompressedLayout.SetIsHeadless(text, true);
 
    grid.Add(image, 0, 0);
    grid.Add(text, 0, 1);
 
    border.BackgroundColor = Color.FromRgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border.Padding = 8;
    border.StrokeThickness = 2;
    border.StrokeShape = new RoundRectangle { CornerRadius = 3 };
 
    var brush = new SolidColorBrush();
    brush.Color = Color.FromRgb(0, 255, 0);
 
    border.Stroke = brush;
    border.Content = grid;
 
    CompressedLayout.SetIsHeadless(border, true);

    return border;
});
```

Currently there is a total of 14 Tiles. However, when I load the Page, it is still very laggy. But I noticed, the lag completely goes away when I rotate the device to landscape. When I rotate back to Portrait, it still stays super fluid... Its just laggy in the beginning and I am trying to find out why.

Anyone got an idea why it is laggy? Or any recommendation on how to resolve it?

Also I played around with a lot of options but nothing seems to help... Its not a lot of content either, the 14 Images all only have a resolution of 256x256. The whole thing ran completely fine on Xamarin.Forms...

Here is the TileViewModel used (no features of BaseViewModel are used):

```cs
public class TileViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    ObservableCollection<Tile> views = new ObservableCollection<Tile>();
    
    public ObservableCollection<Tile> Tiles { get => views; }

    public TileViewModel(ObservableCollection<Tile> views)
    {
        this.views = views;
    }
}
```

And here is the Tile class:

```cs
public class Tile : IHasAttribute
{

    public Dictionary<string, string> Attributes { get; set; }
    public String Text { get; set; }

    public String Id { get; set; }
    public String ImageID { get; set; }

    public ImageSource ImageSource { get; set; }

    public Tile(string id, string name, string imageID)
    {
        Attributes = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        Id = id;
        Text = name;
        ImageID = imageID;
    }

    public String getAttribute(string key)
    {
        if (Attributes.ContainsKey(key)) return Attributes[key];
        return "none";
    }
}
```

I generate the Tiles from an XML file that is pulled from the server, but i basically just create some instances with the constructor and set the ImageSource once available (before the pages load though). I have tried different ImageSources, the type does not seem to matter. The performance only plummets when using different Images, reusing the same URL many times works flawlessly.

Edit: Opened up an issue - https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/17326

Comment: 1. Please help add `tileViewModel` and relevant code to your post to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). 2. The issue looks like it's related with https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/13557 and has been fixed in `8.0.0-preview.3.8149`.

Comment: Hi there @Alexandar, thank you very much for your input! I added the missing code. I hope this is enough context. I also checked out the issue. Does look very similar, I will try to get the project to run on .net 8 and check.

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT Me again, after alot of testing I can say that the issue is not fixed in 8.0.0, even on preview 7. Still the same symptoms. A quick check in the Task-Manager shows insane CPU usage while scrolling.

Comment: Thanks for the update, according to the error message you provided, can you try this workaround:https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9011#issuecomment-1333534818?

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT the crashing apparently solved itself after a few more restarts and deleting the bin and obj folders. After fixing the layout the performance dropped again, it was only running "smoothly" because 4 tiles were visible due to the broken layout.

Comment: Glad to see the issue is being resolved. You can post your solution or findings as an answer as it's helpful to others facing the same problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT sorry for the confusion, my original issue is still not fixed. I did notice it only happens with different Images, if I use the same URL (still multiple ImageSource instances), it doesnt lag at all.

Comment: This could be a potential issue, consider raising an open issue:https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues on Github.